# Pygame mouse detection slows down my program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, mouseevent

I want to make a picture puzzle that uses mouse inputs to move the pieces, I wrote that module to get the mouse inputs but when its used it only lets me close the pygame window with the task manager.

It also seemingly makes the program freeze until one of those if conditions is satisfied.

Should I completely rewrite this module or did I just make a mistake?

Thank you for your help.

```
import Data

import pygame
pygame.init()



def MD():

    event = pygame.event.wait()


    det_gen_pos = None #determen general position # return index 0
    det_gen_mov = None #determen general movement # return index 1

    det_L_D = False #determen left press # return index 2
    det_L_U = False #determen left release # return index 3

    det_M_D = False #determen right press # return index 4
    det_M_U = False #determen right release # return index 5

    det_R_D = False #determem wheel press # return index  6
    det_R_U = False #determen wheel release # return index 7

    # 0 turning forward # 1 turning backwards # 2 stop turning forward # 3 stop turning backwards
    det_W_T = None #determens 4 different states of the wheel # return index 8


    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        det_gen_pos = event.pos
        det_gen_mov = event.rel

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == 1:
            det_L_D = True
        if event.button == 2:
            det_M_D = True
        if event.button == 3:
            det_R_D = True
        if event.button == 4:
            det_W_T = 0
        if event.button == 5:
            det_R_D = 2

        det_gen_pos = event.pos

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        if event.button == 1:
            det_L_U = True
        if event.button == 2:
            det_M_U = True
        if event.button == 3:
            det_R_U = True
        if event.button == 4:
            det_W_T = 1
        if event.button == 5:
            det_R_D = 3

        det_gen_pos = event.pos


    Data.LastMotion.append((det_gen_pos, det_gen_mov, det_L_D, det_L_U, det_M_D, det_M_U, det_R_D, det_R_U ,det_W_T))
    if len(Data.LastMotion) == Data.MotionCount:
        Data.LastMotion.pop(0)

    return Data.LastMotion[len(Data.LastMotion) - 1]
```

Comment: You will need to add the code to the question were `MD()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue it with `pygame.event.wait()`. This will result in the program waiting for an event to occur before continuing, thus "freezing" the program while waiting.

you can try using this method of checking instead:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # Check for left click
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # or any other event types
        # some action
```